# SwiftUI: Creating a Collection from an Array of varying size

Tags: arrays, swiftui, collections, collectionview

New and learning coding. I am trying to create a Collection View in Swift UI that is populated from an array of image names. That array will vary in size each time the user runs each session, because its size is based upon the number of questions they correctly answer. All current attempts have failed because the collection views I build are of fixed grid sizes, so the array size mismatch causes fatal errors. But I can't figure out how to make the collection dynamically add cells to match the incoming array size. Suggestions for how to do this right?

Code of my latest attempt is below. The important array being passed into the view is "fullZoo" array, which is populated from a previous view.

```
// View to make dynamically sized images for the collection---vvvvvvvvv--------------------
struct CollectionViewCell: View {
    static let column = 5
    static let row = 10
    let width = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width/5)-20
    var index = 0
    
    var cellAnimal: String
    
    init(row: Int, column: Int, cellAnimal: String) {
         index = (3 * row) + column + (row * 2)
        self.cellAnimal = cellAnimal
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
//            Text("\(index)")
            Image(cellAnimal)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: width, height: width)
//                .onTapGesture {
//                    print("\(self.index)")
//                }
        }
    }
}
//-------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--------------------------------------------------

struct ZooView: View {
    var fullZoo: [String]
    

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RadialGradient(stops: [
                .init(color: Color(red: 0.1, green: 0.2, blue: 0.45),
                      location: 0.3),
                .init(color: .indigo, location: 0.8)
            ], center: .top, startRadius: 100, endRadius: 700)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                ForEach(0..<CollectionViewCell.row, id: \.self) {i in
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(0..<CollectionViewCell.column, id: \.self) {j in
                            CollectionViewCell(row: i, column: j, cellAnimal: fullZoo[index])
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This code throws an error in the second ForEach loop because of the use of "index" in fullZoo[ ], which again is a mismatch between array size and the collection grid.

Comment: do not use arrays of `Views` (CollectionViewCell) in a `ForEach` loop. Re-structure your code and read again the basics of SwiftUI.